What would a planet need for rain drops to trigger explosions upon making contact with the ground?
The rain of my planet, for some reason, triggers explosions upon making contact with the ground. However, only rain water specifically causes this. Bodies of water like rivers or oceans don't cause any explosions despite being in constant contact with the ground. The unique property of explosions only extend to the specific phenomena of rain water making contact with the ground.
What would the planet need for this to be achieved? If possible, I want the rain water to remain as water-y as possible.

How big an explosion? Large hail can do damage.

Nitroglycerin? "a dense, colorless .. oily, explosive liquid most commonly produced by nitrating glycerol with white fuming nitric acid" .. how you explain nitroglycerin condensing out of the atmosphere to fall as rain I haven't a clue .. maybe we have a chemist who can extrapolate what sort of hell scape of a planet is needed to provide the environmental factors needed?.. and then explain why life is impossible on it :)

@Pelinore airborne bacteria work wonders, you know. The evolutionary value of excreting nitroglycerine is what I wonder about. Religious extremism? Taedium vitae?

@FrançoisJurain "The evolutionary value of excreting nitroglycerine is what I wonder about" the bombardier beetle has your back there, and the answer is self defense, if only it had paid attention in class and taken a different path in developing it's defence systems, we could have something a bit more exciting than glow worms in our woods, instead of little lights and pheromones to attract a mate we could have tunes played by dropping explosives from high branches ;)

@Pelinore so be it. Pick photosynthesizing bacteria to make glycerol out of CO2, UV from the local Sun to produce nitric acid out of ozone, add a few magic enzymes and off you go on a nice answer: the mutant bombardier yeast and its exploding poo.

It all depends on how high up the raindrops fall from and their interaction with the air on the way down.

Biological explosions.  Your planet is much like Earth.  Microbes are found high in the atmosphere, and there is an ozone layer.  However, your planet has an ozone layer much denser than Earth's, perhaps a higher level of CO2, and a lower level of water in the upper atmosphere.  The microorganisms that dwell in its atmosphere have evolved simple "colonial" multicellularity and use this higher-level organization to control their altitude more effectively than Earthly spores.  (Namely, the atmosphere is a bit turbulent; they might unfurl during brief updrafts and "rifle" into dart shapes as they pass through small regions of descending air)  Because they survive so well in the upper atmosphere, the lower atmosphere is more shaded, and not as good an environment to extract energy by photosynthesis.
At altitude, they make use of a minute droplet of stored mineral-rich water attached to each colony, and carbon dioxide, to make ordinary carbohydrates and all the other compounds needed for ordinary Earth life.  The droplet is held safe within the colony, and is far smaller than a raindrop.  But as the colony depletes, it modifies all the surfaces of its vegetative cells with organic peroxide.  To illustrate, CH3-(C=O)-OH + O3 -> CH3-(C=O)-O-O-H + O2.
Organic peroxides are rather infamous - they tend to build up on, say, the lid of a lab bottle of diethyl ether, and cause terrible lab explosions.  The scale of the explosions life intends here is much less, as there are only small deposits of peroxide with little additional fuel.  The colony is always hygroscopic, pulling in any water in the air around it.  When it depletes, it forms into a dart, and plunges into the lower atmosphere, where it takes up water vapor - in other words, nucleates a raindrop.  A particle of silver nitrate can do it, but this organism does it better.  As the raindrops form, they merge, and the amount of explosive in the combined drop grows.
When the drop hits the ground, it contains a large amount of water and however much organic peroxide you need for a suitable little boom.  The boom splatters the raindrop into a fine aerosol.  Each aerosol drop contains one or two reproductive cells liberated from their siblings, accompanied by enough water to make a new colony.  They rapidly surround their drop with a water-repellent membrane.  Using the last of their stored energy, they attempt to adjust their course upward, back to the upper atmosphere.  If the explosions need to be hazardous, this can be explained as a sort of "carnivorous plant" adaptation: the upward-bound aerosols may be as much borrowed blood or flesh as water.

This is clever, so much so that I don't think it matters for the purpose of storytelling whether or not it is actually possible.  It sounds plausible to my non-scientists ears and would be fun in a story.

This is a Frame Challenge... kinda...
If you want every drop to go boom and want a science-y rationale you're out of luck. Such a planet, if it could exist, would be entirely uninhabitable. At least in the beginning.

Every rainstorm would consume whatever it is that makes the explosion when a raindrop hits. Over time, whatever was doing that would be consumed. During the Earth's history there was a 1-2 million (yeah, million) year period where it rained. Pretty much non-stop. That event would have consumed whatever it was that went boom. If it didn't, the billions of years after that would have eventually done it with rare pockets of boomable (Scrabble!) material hanging on here and there.

You don't say that the world must be habitable, but I'm assuming that you need it to be. Habitable + boom = non-scientific... but let's ignore this. What can go boom? One way of looking at it is a chemical reaction between water and something else — but that's already been suggested. Let's try another tack.

Nitrogen Triiodide is a contact explosive. We played around with it in high school. Not the smartest thing we ever did! But it isn't H2O that makes the boom, it's the impact of the water droplet onto the planet's surface that makes the boom.

Once again, if you try to make this science-realistic you're going to have trouble. I don't think triiodide is a naturally-occuring compound. If it is, I wouldn't be surprised to hear it's rare. Iodine isn't exactly rampant — and making it rampant takes us back to the habitability problem.
So... frame challenge.

Not to mention that having raindrops create explosions means that they will erode the planet's surface far faster. After a bit, there won't be any land left to explode on.

Frame Challenge
Does it have to be an Explosion Explosion or something that is Explosion-like.
Initially I was thinking of either an Alkaline Metal solution (like has been suggested) or a contact explosive that is set-off by the impact of the raindrop (as also suggested) - but neither of these are great.
But... What if it was not what we would call an Explosion technically, but something that would seem like an explosion?
So here is my suggestion:
A very strongly electrically charged surface
I am thinking very strong tectonic activity combined with a unique composition of elements in the crust make the ground extremely charged. Lakes and Rivers being close to this also have this charge, but Rain? That is formed in the upper-atmosphere and has the opposite charge.
When the Rain falls, once it gets close enough, something something an Arc is formed - so you have small localized bursts of lightning.
Instead of coming down from the sky, they just exist at Ground level. You get a Crack, a flash of light, a lot of heat - everything that a lay-person would refer to as an explosion.
I am sure that having a ground that is charged is violating all sorts of Electrical theory (JBH dont hate me) - but something something special planetary conditions something and that is as good as I can come up with.

Option 1: the ground is lava.
When the rain drops fall on it, they are instantly vaporized, more or less what you get when you spray water on a pan which you left on the burning stove empty.
Option 2: the ground has large exposed pockets of alkaline metals like magnesium, sodium or potassium, which burn in contact with water.
In both options large bodies of water would quickly remove the cause for the explosions, making them possible only when water interacts with the surface in droplets.

Option 2 is great. There are several materials that react violently with water. The problem is keeping them from reacting with the water that is always in the air.

Perhaps a large concentration of lithium in the soil might be able to do it.  Lithium reacts violently when exposed to water.

It wouldn't last long. Lithium salts are soluble in water and will be washed out by excess rain in a few years.
